# How to use df.value_counts with csv files?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv

I need help about the function df.value_counts: I'm coding a program that takes the informations of a csv file to create an other csv file but with everything reorganized as I wish. With that, I discovered the df.value_counts function, which is perfect for me, because what I have in my csv file is float numbers, and I want to count the amount of each number there is in the file: gonna explain, I got that list for example, [10.48, 11.22, 13.26, 9.87]. What I want to do is count the amount of 9.00's, 10.00's, 11.00's, and so on, in order to use it after. But I have a problem, I don't know how to extract all the data I get, I just get the information that there are for example 4 10.88, 4 12.32, but I can do nothing with this.

(If you want to understand the use of all of this, I'm what we call a speedcuber, I solve Rubik's Cubes in 11 seconds in average, and I want to see in 100 solves how many times I get 10 seconds solves, 9 seconds solves, and so I'm coding this in order to do that automatically.)
I hope you'll understand what I want (remember that i'm a 16 years old french student lmao), dont' hesitate to ask me for some more informations if needed !

Comment: Round to integers then value counts

Comment: Show us your dataframe (please copy text, not images)

Comment: Thank you, it worked ! (I figured it out, using an other way to convert it into integers)